# Adding PdfPCell in iText PdfPtable doesnt work anymore

Tags: itext

I have created several PdfPTable without problem, but now I dont know what is wrong. Fourth line doesnt displayed.

```
    table = new PdfPTable(4);
    table.setSpacingBefore(10);
    columnWidths = new float[] {60,10,10,10};
    table.setWidths(columnWidths);

    PdfPCell cellFooter = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Rows One", ARIAL_12_BOLD));
    table.addCell(cellFooter);
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
        table.addCell("");
    }

    cellFooter = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row Two", ARIAL_12_BOLD));
    table.addCell(cellFooter);

    for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
        table.addCell("");
    }

    cellFooter = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Row Three", ARIAL_12_BOLD));
    cellFooter.setColspan(4);
    table.addCell(cellFooter);

    // Row Four not displayed
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++){
        table.addCell("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer, let me ask you this: *How many pixels in height is an empty string?*

The simplest way to get around this is to just add *something*. You should be able to just use:

```
table.addCell(" ");
```

However, if you're changing font sizes elsewhere the height might be different so you might want to explicitly set the font (and thus the height) of the empty cell:

```
table.addCell(new Phrase(" ", ARIAL_12_BOLD));
```

You could also explicitly define heights on cells but this is usually the easiest way.